# DevonThink Pro Office execute script when intelligent folder changes content

Tags: macos, applescript

I have DevonThink Pro Office for Mac and I would like to execute a script when an intelligent Folder changes its contents.

In detail: 
    I have some RSS feeds in DevonThink and intelligent folders which search some keywords in all my RSS feeds. I need a solution to execute a script when new entries match my keywords (i.e. the intelligent folder get a new item). When I look at the properties of an intelligent folder, there is a script selection field, may be this could help.

The script should popup an MessageBox or better send an email.

I hope someone can give me some hints to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some hints. I don't know how to control DevonThink Pro Office but if your RSS feeds are saved to a file on your disk then there may be another way. OS X has the capability itself to watch a folder and run a script if changes happen to that folder using a process called "launchd".

So here's how I would do this if they're files on the disk. I'd create a launchd folder watcher and have it launch an applescript when it detects a change to the files in the watched folder, like when a new file is added to the folder or the modification date of one of the current files changes. The applescript would read the text of the RSS files and search if the text contains one of your keywords... and if one is detected then execute the script you want.

It's rather simple once you know how. Just google for a launchd folder watcher plist file, there's plenty out there, and then write the appropriate applescript code to search for your keywords.

I hope that gives you something you can work with. Good luck.

Comment: Ah thats an interrest solution :) I will try it this way when I have time soon. Thanks, I will let you know the solution then.